# Find the orthogonal proyection of $x^4$.

Tags: functional-analysis

A doubt.  $V=Span(1,x,x^3)$ generates $L^2([0,1])$?

I ask it because I am trying to find an orthonormal basis from V and then calculate the orthogonal projection of x^4 but I got that doubt.

I reached the next orthonormal set

$V'=Span(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ with $v_1=1$, $v_2=(x-1/2)/|v_2|_2$ and $v_3=(x^3-1/4-1/10(x-1/2))/|v_3|_2 $ and like uses that $x^4=\sum_{k=1}^{3} a_kv_k$ for find the orthogonal proyection of $x^4$ in $V'$...but I am somewhat lost with what arose in doubt

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No. The span of $\{1,x,x^2\}$ does not span $L^2([0,1])$, because it is is infinite dimensional, so it cannot be spanned by only three vectors.
The main claim of this answer is that $\{1,x,x^2\}$ does not span $L^2([0,1])$, and not as may be suggested otherwise by some comments.

Comment: This is in reverse. It is rather that $L^2([0,1])$ cannot be spanned by finitely many vectors, and is therefore infinite dimensional. And thus the main claim of this answer, namely that the dimension is strictly greater than 3, is still entirely unsubstantiated, well-known though it may be.

Comment: If the question is "Is the dimension at most 3?" an answer that says little more than a statement of the fact "The dimension is infinite", without any hint of reasoning behind it, is a poor answer in my opinion.

Comment: You are certainly entitled to your incomprehensible opinions, Arthur.

Comment: You're still answering the question "Does $\{1,x,x^2\}$ span $L^2$?" With "No, because it is known that you need infinitely many vectors to span it." Claiming that something is known, without any actual reasoning or even a link to more resources, is still a poor answer in my opinion. But you're entitled to letting it stands as it is.